# Project-based matrix authentication with multibranch pipelines

Tags: jenkins, authorization, multibranch-pipeline

I have troubles getting projects-based matrix authentication getting to work with multibranch pipeline jobs. User "test" only has minimal permissions on the global level: he can log in but not see anything. Then I grant the user some permissions via a job's Jenkinsfile:

`properties([authorizationMatrix(['hudson.model.Item.Build:test', 'hudson.model.Item.Cancel:test', 'hudson.model.Item.Read:test']))`

The configuration is applied once the job runs, because I can see the corresponding settings in the job configuration page. But user "test" still does not see the job and if it tries to access it directly via a URL that works for other users he only gets a 404.

What I am doing wrong or is this even supposed to work that way?

Comment: We have the some problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, we did not.